# Openshift Python multiple httpd instances

Tags: python, apache, openshift

I have a Python web application (using WSGI) deployed on Openshift. The application is quite memory greedy. What I have noticed is that there are several instance of Apache httpd service deployed at all times. That means the memory usage of my gear is multiplied by the number of these processes and the application crashes pretty often.

I don't have lots of traffic yet, so there is no need to have multiple httpd running.

Is there any way to configure Python cartridge to limit it to a **single httpd process**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the OpenShift Python cartridge and its default setup, only two of those processes should actually have copies of your application running in it. The other httpd processes are the parent monitor process and the Apache child worker processes which will proxy requests to the processes which are actually running your web application.

If you need control to reduce it down to one process, then you would need to follow:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/01/using-alternative-wsgi-servers-with.html

to override the standard setup and use mod_wsgi-express instead. This will default to using one process for your application and allow you to control both number of processes and threads for the application processes.

If you are seeing lots of memory use, then it could just be your application code, or there is an outside chance you are seeing memory issues due to use of older mod_wsgi as there are some odd corner cases which can cause extra memory usage because of how Apache works. If you use mod_wsgi-express it will use the latest and avoid those problems.

So try mod_wsgi-express and if still have memory issues, suggest you get on the mod_wsgi mailing list to get help debugging it.

Comment: Your instructions from the blog worked like a charm. Now I have only one mod_wsgi-express process so no need to double memory resources. Thanks a lot.